# mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting (null) inside a mounted nfs share

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, mount, nfs

I set up four nfs shares and I can mount all of them, anywhere I want **but inside each other**. If I try to do so, I see this error message:
`mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting (null)` 
The host is Ubuntu 16.04, the client is Linux Mint 18.2 (VM). I could mount the shares in each other on Deepin 15.4 and 15.4.1 but cannot on 15.5 beta.

My share definitions are like this: `/path/to/share  25.61.29.206(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)`
(they only differr in path)

Why can't I mount the shares into each other on the client?

Comment: That is very odd, because the server doesn't know nor care where you're mounting the filesystems on the client. Can you give more complete details about the export list on the server and the client's exact mount commands? Please use paths like `/a/b` and `/a/b/c` instead of `/path/to/share`, because the relationships between the paths may be important.

Comment: Sure. [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26040277/) are the shares on the server, and the [mount commands](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26040261/) on the client. IP address of 'server' is 25.22.3.242 by the way.

Comment: Thanks. Which `sudo mount` command fails?

Comment: `sudo mount server:/home/weylyn1/Downloads /media/weylyn1/data/Downloads` and `sudo mount server:/home/weylyn1/Pictures /media/weylyn1/data/Pictures`

Comment: Could you add the output of `cat /var/lib/nfs/etab` on the server ?

Comment: Sure. [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26044948/) it is.

Comment: Now that I checked again, the shares cannot be mounted inside each other on Deepin either. Same error.

Comment: Have you checked the SELinux context on the directory, in case SELinux is enabled ?